# android 6.0 NullPointerException while getting photo path

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I use the following code to get the photo path where the image has been saved after taking a photo with the camera and I get a NullPointerException only on Android 6.0 on Nexus 5. 
Before upgrading to Android 6.0 on the same phone it worked well.

```
final Uri selectedImageUri =  data == null ? null : data.getData();
String selectedImagePath = null;
selectedImagePath = getPath(getActivity(), selectedImageUri);


@TargetApi(19)
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}
```

It throws a NullPointerException inside 
 `DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)`

**UPDATE**

I found that the problem is in uri being null.
Here the code to retrieve the URI

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO){
        if( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            final boolean isCamera;
            if(data == null)
            {
                isCamera = true;
            }
            else
            {
                final String action = data.getAction();
                if(action == null)
                {
                    isCamera = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    isCamera = action.equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            }

            String createdImagePath = null;
            if(isCamera)
            {
                createdImagePath = mCallbacks.getCurrentPhotoPath();
            }
            else
            {
                final Uri selectedImageUri =  data == null ? null : data.getData();
                String selectedImagePath = null;

                selectedImagePath = getPath(getActivity(), selectedImageUri);
```

Comment: No... it throws NullPointerException somewhere inside #isDocumentUri method. Attach at least partial Log output... Isn't possible that context or uri is null?

Comment: @VizGhar that seems most liekly, but if so, that's poor API design, it would be better if `DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri` checked for null parameters and threw IllegalArgumentException

Comment: If it is problem inside the function, then it is failing either in `DocumentContract.isDocumentUri -> uri.getPathSegments();` or `DocumentContract.isDocumentsProvider -> context.getPackageManager()`

Comment: just do null checks by yourself

Comment: @VizGhar you are right, the uri was null. I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I found the solution.
I have to add another null check here :

```
                if(data == null || data.getData() == null)
```

It looks like on Android 6.0 the Intent returned after taking a photo by camera isn't null like in previous OS version, BUT it contains no data.
So checking if data is null like I did until now it's not enough.